# PCL:How to picking other PointCloud in the PCL Visualization

Tags: point-cloud-library, mouse-picking

I want picking other PointCloud but the "cloud" in the PCL Visualization.

However the registerAreaPickingCallback() doesn't support pass PointCloud arg.
By default,only the default pointcloud:"cloud" is avalible and the indices of the callback areaPickingEvent only include the default pointcloud:"cloud".

I can't found any information about it in the PCL website.

I wonder how to do it,can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the relavent issue at GitHub.
At here:[#978](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/978)

And the contributors have solved it.[#3763](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/3763)

They will release it at PCL-1.12.0